# How to check if a string is encrypted or not?

Tags: java, encryption

I am using this encryption method to encrypt and decrypt a certain string :-

```
package encryption;

import java.security.Key;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class AES {

     private static final String ALGO = "AES";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = 
        new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }
    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
}

}
```

It works fine.

**The issue is that how will i get to know that the string which is to be decrypted is encrypted ?**

I mean i could pass a long "not encrypted" string to the decrypt method and it still will work.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

There's no definitive way to tell; the only thing you can do is look at a string and see if it looks like something intelligible (roughly speaking, something for which `file` would return something more specific than "data"). Unless you have some characteristic that you can use to identify "plain text" (maybe everything's ASCII, or all Unicode code points for $LANGUAGE), there's no inherent difference between ciphertext and arbitrary binary data.

Comment: In theory you can not, however in practice you can do things like looking at the distrobution of all the characters. In this case because they are expecting a base64 string it should be pretty easy.

Comment: Great explanation. Not many people get that encrypted data ideally should be the same as truly random data.

Comment: @PeterMichealLacey-Bordeaux But what if someone encrypts a Base64 string?

Comment: @chrylis Yes I completely agree there are ways to break it, I was just suggesting something that might work for some purposes. If they are encrypting evenly distributed base64 strings then you have to use stuff like checking the padding or some encryption method that handles this stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You can determine if something is encrypted with a particular key, algorithm, mode, and padding scheme by simply trying to decrypt it.

If you're decrypting the data, you know the padding scheme being used, and you can verify if the padding is correct when you try to decrypt it. If you cannot reliably strip the padding from the original message, you know you have a problem!

One of the benefits of the CBC mode, which is supported in almost every widely used cryptography library containing symmetric ciphers (like AES) is that each block depends on the previous one in terms of its data. This means that errors will propagate and you are more likely to fail to decrypt data that was not actually encrypted or has been corrupted accidentally in some fashion.

I believe that this is probably the best bang for your lines of code to test if the data passed in was encrypted with the specific key, algorithm, mode, and padding scheme.

**EDIT**

But, if you need to verify with high certainty that the key is correct, you need to add a message authentication code (MAC) at the end of your ciphertext or plaintext.

You can form your message like this:

```
CIPHERTEXT = ENCRYPT(KEY_1, PADDING, MODE, PLAINTEXT)
MESSAGE = CIPHERTEXT || HMAC(KEY_2, CIPHERTEXT)
```

`CIPHERTEXT` is defined as the result of encryption of plaintext under a specific key, padding, and mode of operation

`MESSAGE` is defined as the result of `CIPHERTEXT` having the `HMAC` result binary-concatenated (`||`) to it.

`KEY_1` is a cryptographically secure key independent of `KEY_2`, another cryptographically secure key.

The reason you want to compute the `HMAC` against the `CIPHERTEXT` is because you don't want to have to actually perform decryption to verify if the message is legitimate.

You will have to start an encrypted session and then exchange `KEY_2` over that encrypted channel, meaning you have added key management overhead and code complexity, but you have a 1/1^256 (at the very least) probability of seeing an incorrect message pass through the `HMAC` check.

Once you verify the result of `HMAC` you can be certain the message is probably actually encrypted under `KEY_1`, assuming no leaks have happened since the start of the session or the lifetime of the message.

Comment: This is helpful, but it's worth noting that the default padding scheme -- [PKCS7/PKCS5 padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) -- is not really designed to detect an incorrect key. For example, if the length is such that only one byte of padding is used, then the probability of an *incorrect* key passing the padding check is 1/256. That may not be good enough for many applications.

Comment: @GregS I went ahead and suggested an alternative which covers your concern. I agree, it's a bit funky to try and rely on padding being correct. It's just one step in the real error checking. I would definitely, in my applications, be using my more complicated alternative. But I am assuming this user is just testing the waters and not implementing a production solution, thus my first explanation was more of guidance than recommendation. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are no perfect answers to this question, as there is no 100% sure way to know if something is encrypted. However it should be randomly distributed across all possible base64 strings which means it should look a lot different than plaintext. One way you can tell the difference between english and base64 encrypted strings is to see how many spaces there are.

There are 92 spaces in this post, but the character space does not appear in base64. If you are dealing with stuff other than plaintext English it will get more interesting.

Comment: While there is no 100% sure way, as you state, there is one that is such a good chance that if you did happen to find a way to fool it, you would have broken the cipher... making this all irrelevant. My answer details that solution. Statistical analysis is less perfect.

Comment: Ah yeah I wasn't thinking about the padding.

Comment: If it were ECB, I wouldn't really have thought of a nice way to do it probably, other than add some kind of MAC and verifying it under an independent key. But that would add a lot of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly possible, assuming the string is long enough. [Those guys are detecting encrypted keys in memory dumps](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/sec08/tech/full_papers/halderman/halderman_html/). Of course, there's no 100% guarantee - simple contrexample, you can encode encoded string, therefore your input looks already like a key.

Generally, encrypted, encoded or hashed byte sequences **looks like random sequences.** They have higher entropy, the distribution of bits is more homogenous, you can't compress them etc.

Best try is to analyse how randomly the bits are distributed. For BASE64 you analyse only 6 bits etc.

Comment: This is a good point. You can actually detect sequences that "look random". But a simple cryptographically secure random number generator can also fool this. It also doesn't verify if the string is encrypted under the key specified, which will result in a failure to decrypt anyway, so the detection of the data being encrypted becomes pointless. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a symmetric encryption/decryption scheme, where both sides can encrypt and decrypt messages using the same key, which is known **only** to them.

Both sides can agree on a correctness-verification method, for example, CRC.

Unlike with the key, which must remain a secret, this method can be publicly announced.

Only owners of the secret key will be able to generate an authentic encrypted string, which can be verified using this method after decryption.

Any other string sent to decryption will simply fail the CRC test.

BTW, the authentication method is usually a hashing algorithm such as SHA, HMAC, etc. due to its nature, CRC would generally be more vulnerable to chosen-ciphertext attacks, where a malicious party generates random strings hoping that some of them will be detected as genuine.

Comment: CRC is not cryptographically secure and appending it to the ciphertext will leak information about the plaintext.

Comment: Well, I used CRC as an example of a possible authentication method. Did not say it was a safe one, and explicitly stated the ones that are typically used for authentication. I also added a note on CRC right after that (although that may have taken place during or immediate after your note). In any case, your down-vote is extremely unwelcome in this case. I don't mind taking ones when I'm wrong, but in this case, the CRC itself was not the main point of the answer!!!

Comment: No worries! Since you did clarify and explained the chosen ciphertext vulnerability and I commented before you made your update, I'll retract my downvote. -- Actually, I just tried to do so, and it said it's locked. If you edit it, I can make the change.

Comment: Locked as in, you edited it and I downvoted at the exact same time, so it looked like I downvoted your most recent version. You can't change votes after a few minutes. So, SO thinks you haven't changed the post and it won't let me retract my downvote. If you edit any part of the post, even formatting, it will let me do that. I wanted my downvote to be effective for the older version of the post that did not have the clarification in it.

Answer (score -2):

Most encrypted text contains "�"

Comment: This doesn't mean encrypted. This generally means invalid unicode, which can sometimes mean it's encrypted - but can mean many more things.